# Application Context Path without Web Request

Tags: spring, grails

Is there any way to get context path in Grails (or Spring) without web request?

For example, at the time the beans get initiated by Spring (when app started), there is no web request made yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Holders](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html) class for accessing the application context. Inside it there's the `servletContext`, which allows you to read the context path:

`grails.util.Holders.applicationContext.servletContext.contextPath`

The `Holders` class also allows you to access to the `grailsApplication` and the `Config`, among other things.